# How to stop Safari from reloading after getting an internet connection back?

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari

If I am using Safari on example an iPad with internet connection, I then minimize safari and go to iPad settings, turn the wifi off and then open up Safari again I get a pop up saying that there's no internet connection and the page doesn't try to reload. I then go back to settings, turn wifi on and go back to Safari, now the page immediately reloads and I wonder how I can stop this? I only want it to submit if I click a certain button.

Is this something that's easy to do with jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory issue; Safari will drop your page if the device runs low on memory.

There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: But like I said if I don't have an internet connection I can still use the form and insert data into the local database and once I get connection back I can transfer all that data to a remote server. However, If I do have an internet connection when I open up safari it reloads the page and submit all the rows in the database which I don't want (until the user is done with all the input).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just a coincidence that it's running out of memory when it reconnects.

Comment: If you close all other Safari tabs and reboot the iPad (hold down the power button), does it still happen?

Comment: yeah every time you open up safari it tries to reload whatever was the last page. If you have internet connection (wifi on) it reloads, if you don't you get a pop up saying no internet connection and the page doesn't reload but you can still use it locally.

Comment: I guess it's ok if it's reload but I don't want it to submit the form on page reload, only if the save button is clicked. Maybe that makes it a bit easier.

Comment: You should use a POST-Redirect-GET pattern.